# Automatic session timeout in php

Tags: session, timeout

Im doing session timeout with php. Im calling php
through ajax. After X seconds of inactivity, if a user
sends a request it is redirected to login page as session has already expired.

How do I send a session timeout message back to browser automatically
and not waiting for a request trigger?

Like, I should have a thread running in the background to check the time
always? Do you have ideas guys?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sending a request from the server to the browser via ajax is known as long polling, or "comet". It is a proven technique, but now without pitfalls.

For one, a connection need be kept open for each user. That's a lot of overhead, so it should be done with something like NodeJS. Even so, the long poll need be reset every 20s or so, which result in fickle code. Newer browsers introduce websockets, which improve things but require a framework with fallback mechanisms. The question is whether it's worth it for your application.

What I would do in your situation is implement the same timeout mechanism in JavaScript. That way, the user gets a nice message when the session times out in JavaScript, and the server enforces the timeout in case the user bypasses the browser for some reason.

Comment: I agree, this is definitely the right direction to go. You could use JavaScript's setTimeout and have it follow similar logic to what you're doing on the server side.